# Try to insert any image from an array into an object

Tags: javascript, class

I try to add an image to my object at different speeds
**Constructor**

```
this.imagePaths = ['./assets/Bill-Gates.png', './assets/steve-jobs.png', './assets/zuckerberg.png'];
this.elementImg.src = `./assets/${() => { changeImage }};`;
```

**function to changeImage**

```
changeImage = () => {
    this.speed < 6 ? this.imagePaths[0] : (this.speed > 6 && this.speed < 9) ? this.imagePaths[1] : this.speed >= 9 ? this.imagePaths[2]
}
```

Now I try with a ternary operator to add an image to the elementtImgSrc depending on the speed.

Comment: `this.elementImg.src = \`./assets/${changeImage()}\`;` ?

Comment: This code `this.elementImg.src = "./assets/${() => { changeImage }};"  ` is going to produce a path of `./assets/./assets/Bill-Gates.png`.  I think your code should look something like this `this.elementImg.src = ${changeImage()}`

Comment: Yes, thank you for the replies. However, what is wrong with the query? It shows the error 'unexpectetd token' but why